# IMAP Export/Import

Tags: microsoft-outlook, imap, export, import

The business I work for has tasked me to oversee an email provider change and since this isn't my strong suit (I'm a graphic designer), I wanted to confirm that what I'm about to do is correct.

The business has 5 email accounts, all use IMAP, all use Outlook as their client. They are switching their provider from one company to another. Do I just need to export the inbox and all subfolders to a PST file to save the messages then import the PST file once the new server settings have been added?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You'll definitely want to get a backup of *everyone's* inboxes before switching. I bet your existing email provider could do that. The new company *may* be able to import old inboxes, too. Ask them what (if any) formats they support, and coordinate with your existing provider to get backups in the right format.

Comment: Thanks for your help, so there wouldn't be an issue importing the PST files if they were exported from an IMAP account?

Comment: I've never tried it.

Answer (score -1):

If you only want to back up email items, just exporting all the email items to local PST files. If you also need to do this for Calendar, Contacts, Tasks, please also make sure you also backed up these items to PST files. See [this article](https://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/backupandrestore.htm#imap) for a detailed guide.